# How to connect to Oracle from AppHarbor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, oracle, appharbor

I would like to deploy my MVC 3 application to AppHarbor and have it connect to a hosted EC2 instance.

The necessary permissions have been granted between the 2 security groups, but I was wondering about the Oracle client software, is that installed on the application servers at AppHarbor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Oracle client software is not installed on AppHarbor, but you can add it as a [feature request here](http://feedback.appharbor.com). It is however rare that application specific software is installed on the application servers, so figuring out an alternative solution is probably the way to go. A couple of suggestions:

**Bin deploying:**
According to [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224986/odp-net-deployment-without-installation) the client library needs to be installed, but you might want to test the approach "Fat Deployment" approach described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193112/odp-net-and-clickonce-possible).

**Managed ODP.NET library:**
It seems like a fully managed ODP.NET library from Oracle (that won't require client software to be installed on the servers) is in the works and there should be a public beta available sometime soon. There are more details [on the Oracle forums](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2216233) where you can also contact the ODP.NET product manager to be included in the private beta.

Comment: So it's not supported out of the box is your answer? How are the drivers for the other database applications installed, or is everything managed? Personally, I just went through a year of the ODP.NET beta (Christian Shay) for Entity Framework and the end product was horrible.

Comment: Yes it's not supported out the box. No database drivers are  currently installed on the servers except for the ones includes in Windows Server 2008 R2.